# 'must' function not working in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and working with a database. I would like to do a query like this:

`curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/project/flat_order/_search?pretty=true -d'
{   query:{
        bool:{
            must:{range:{created_at:{gte:"2012-01-01 00:00:00",lte:"2012-02-01 00:00:00"}}}},
            {should:[{term:{status:"canceled"}}],minimum_number_should_match:1}
             }
          }
}'`

and I am getting an error. 
`"error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[YfeNrRnOTOqLOtQt65uPVw][project][1]: SearchParseException[[project][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { query:{ bool:{ must:{range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}}}, {should:[{term:{status:\"canceled\"}}],minimum_number_should_match:1} } } }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[project] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name\n at [Source: [B@3742925a; line: 1, column: 102]]; }{[YfeNrRnOTOqLOtQt65uPVw][project][2]: SearchParseException[[project][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { query:{ bool:{ must:{range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}}}, {should:[{term:{status:\"canceled\"}}],minimum_number_should_match:1} } } }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[project] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name\n at [Source: [B@3742925a; line: 1, column: 102]]; }]",
  "status" : 500
}`

What to do? 
Thanks in advance.

This is the error I am getting without those braces(enclosing should)
`"error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[YfeNrRnOTOqLOtQt65uPVw][project][0]: SearchParseException[[project][0]: query[created_at:[1325376000000 TO 1328054400999]],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { query:{ bool:{ must:{range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}}}, should:[{term:{status:\"canceled\"}}],minimum_number_should_match:1 } } }]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[project][0]: query[created_at:[1325376000000 TO 1328054400999]],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [term]]]; }{[YfeNrRnOTOqLOtQt65uPVw][project][4]: SearchParseException[[project][4]: query[created_at:[1325376000000 TO 1328054400999]],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { query:{ bool:{ must:{range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}}}, should:[{term:{status:\"canceled\"}}],minimum_number_should_match:1 } } }]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[project][4]: query[created_at:[1325376000000 TO 1328054400999]],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [term]]]; }]",
  "status" : 500
}`

Comment: if I remove the must statement the command is working properly.

Comment: "What to do?" Fix the error. If you need more detail about the fix, please provide more detail about the error :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error detail, I believe the problem is that you've got an extra level of nesting for your `should` clause which you shouldn't have. Instead of:

```
must: { ... },
{ should: { ... },
  minimum_number_should_match:1}
}
```

Try:

```
must: { ... },
should: { ... },
minimum_number_should_match:1}
```

EDIT: Your edited code looks like this is your query:

```
query:{ bool:{ must:{range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",
lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}}}, should:[{term:status:\"canceled\"}}],
minimum_number_should_match:1 }
```

which, formatted, would be:

```
query:{ 
 bool:{ 
  must:{
   range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}
  }
 },
 should: [
  {term:{status:\"canceled\"}}
 ],
 minimum_number_should_match:1
}
```

... which has the `should` *outside* the `bool` part. In other words, you've got too many closing braces after your `must` clause. I believe it should be:

```
query:{ 
 bool:{ 
  must:{
   range:{created_at:{gte:\"2012-01-01 00:00:00\",lte:\"2012-02-01 00:00:00\"}}
  },
  should: [
   {term:{status:\"canceled\"}}
  ],
  minimum_number_should_match:1
 } 
}
```

Comment: @Vipul: Well given that it follows the schema more closely than what you started with, please post the error when you try that form.

Comment: i have poster it in my question only. Have a look

Comment: @Vipul: It would really help if you'd post your query as well, properly formatted - but it now looks like you've got the `should` *after* the closing brace of the `bool`. Will edit to show this...